# Python writing to file per character instead of per string

Tags: python, io, tuples

Suppose I have K and V. K contains a tuple

```
('String1', 'String2')
```

while V is a floating-point number

```
0.00324
```

What I'm trying to do is to write both into a text file like this:

```
('String1', 'String2') 0.00324
```

or

```
String1 String2 0.00324
```

My code is this:

```
for k,v in bigrams_frequency.items():
    number_unigrams = vocabulary.count(k[0])
    if number_unigrams == 0:
        continue;
    v = v / number_unigrams
    print(k,v)
    f2.write('\n'.join('%s %s' % (k,v)))
```

However, when I open the text file, the output looks like this:

```
(
'
S
t
r
i
n
g
1
.
.
.
```

What could be causing Python to print like this? How do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried formatting both `K` and `V` into one big string and write the big string to the file?

Comment: `f2.write("%s %d\n" % (' '.join(k), v))`

Comment: yeah @WhatsThePoint , use  a formatter before you write to a text file

Comment: Still doens't display anything

Comment: @Jessie how's that nothing is displayed, are you getting any kind of error message ?

Comment: @PYPL Not really. Nothing is in the text file when I tried to use your code though.

Comment: are you closing your file after finishing the write operation?

Comment: it should work along with my proposed code, you just have to make sure you close your file after finishing all operations with it.

Comment: What do you think `'\n'.join('string')` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments here is the code;

```
K=("string1","string2")
V=0.00324
file = open("test.txt","a")
file.write("{} {}".format(K,V))
file.close()
```

and it produces this output the file which you specified as a desired output in your question;

```
('string1', 'string2') 0.00324
```

you can also use a `with` statement when writing to files because a `with` statement automatically closes the file so you dont need to explicitly close it so for your example it will be;

```
with open("test","a") as file:
    file.write("{} {}".format(K,V))
```

just dont forget to indent where you need the file because as soon as it isnt indented anymore the file will close

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong understanding of [str.join(xx)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function. This function "return a string which is concatenation of the string in the iterable xx". You can use str.format() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here - `f2.write('\n'.join('%s %s' % (k,v)))`.
The join method expects an iterable (like a list) in the parameters. When you give it the string 'String1 String2 Float', it 'joins' every two letters with a new line.
It seems all that you want to do is write every entry in a new line (not every letter!), so replace the line with something like `f2.write('{} {}\n'.format(k, v))`
If you haven't come across `format` yet, read up about it [here](https://pyformat.info/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for k,v in bigrams_frequency.items():
    # Other code
    f2.write('{}{}\n'.format(join(k),v) )
```

And, it will be just fine.